# Move a Python GTK3 window with headerbar during a process

Tags: python, gtk3

I like the GTK Headerbar. But when I use it, I can't move the window during a process. What is the a good way to stop the headerbar freezing my window?

Regards

example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

import time


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="HeaderBarTest")
        self.connect("destroy", lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.set_border_width(20)

        # header bar
        if True:
            hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
            hb.set_show_close_button(True)
            hb.props.title = "HeaderBarTest"
            self.set_titlebar(hb)

        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Sleep")
        self.box.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.sleep_function)

        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def sleep_function(self, widget=None):
        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyWindow()
```

edit:
[Window freezes after clicking of button in python GTK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199057/window-freezes-after-clicking-of-button-in-python-gtk3)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use multiprocessing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

import time

from multiprocessing import Process


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="HeaderBarTest")
        self.connect("destroy", lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.set_border_width(20)

        # header bar
        if True:
            hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
            hb.set_show_close_button(True)
            hb.props.title = "Convert2Html"
            self.set_titlebar(hb)

        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Sleep")
        self.box.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_sleep_button_clicked)

        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_sleep_button_clicked(self, widget):
        p = Process(target=self.sleep_function)
        p.start()

    def sleep_function(self, widget=None):
        print "start"
        time.sleep(6)
        print "end"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyWindow()
```